# сравнение списков игнорирую регистр Python

Tags: python

есть список имен:

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Garri', 'Tom', 'Kris', 'Mary']
```

есть новый список:

```
new_users = ['stas', 'john', 'tom', 'Garri','mary']
```

Как сравнить игнорирую регистр. Чтоб одинаковые имена не выводились. У меня выводятся одинаковые имена Tom и Mary. Никак не пойму как использовать lower()

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Garri', 'Tom', 'Kris', 'Mary']
new_users = ['stas', 'john', 'tom', 'Garri','mary']
for name in new_users:
    if name in current_users:
        print('name not available')
    else:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `lower()`-метод вот так:

```py
>>> new_lower = [name.lower() for name in new_users] 
>>> current_lower = [name.lower() for name in current_users]
>>> new_lower
['stas', 'john', 'tom', 'garri', 'mary']
>>> current_lower
['admin', 'garri', 'tom', 'kris', 'mary']
```

а теперь через вашу логику:

```py
for name in new_lower:
    if name in current_lower:
        print(f'{name} not available')
    else:
        print(name)
```

Вывод будет таким:

```py
stas
john
tom not available
garri not available
mary not available
```

Comment: `print(f'{name} not available')`

Comment: А так вот, что имелось в виду=), спасибо

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, теперь понял как делать.

Answer (score 2):

Список `current_users` преобразуется в множество `occupied_names`. Проверка принадлежности для `set` делается быстрее чем для списка. `occupied_names` содержит имена в нижнем регистре.

Новые имена по одному переводятся в нижний регистр и сверяются с `occupied_names`. На печать отправляются оригинальные имена:

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Garri', 'Tom', 'Kris', 'Mary']
new_users = ['stas', 'john', 'tom', 'Garri','mary']

occupied_names = set(map(str.lower, current_users))

for name in new_users:                                                      
    if name.lower() in occupied_names:
        print(f'{name} not available')
    else:
        print(name)
```

> ```
> stas
> john
> tom not available
> Garri not available
> mary not available
> ```

Comment: С множеством неплохо, я пока еще не дошел в изучении до них, но получается на одну строчку короче. Обязательно разберусь и с этим вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо Дмитрий. Теперь понял как делать. В итоге вот что получилось. Получается чтобы сравнить старый список и новый список игнорируя регистр нужно сделать копию обоих списков со строчными буквами. В итоге результат который нужен. Если есть вариант проще пишите.

```
current_users = ['admin', 'Garri', 'Tom', 'Kris', 'Mary']
new_users = ['stas', 'john', 'tom', 'Garri','mary']
copy_current_user = [name.lower() for name in current_users] 
copy_new_user = [name.lower() for name in new_users]
for name in new_users:                                                      
    if name in copy_current_user: # игнорирую регистр
        print('name not available')
    else:
        print(name)
```

```
stas
john
name not available
name not available
name not available
```